# Change camera position.z with mouse wheel in threejs

Tags: camera, three.js

Has anyone any idea how to change the `camera.position.z` (with mouse wheel) of the camera, and make a scroll effect?

When I try with a variable it does not work.

Comment: I'm unsure what "and make scroll effect" means, but to change the camera position and stop the page scrolling you would...add a `scroll` event listener to the renderers dom element and in the listener function change the camera position and call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the page scrolling.

Comment: i have a mesh  vertical,and i want to move the camera to z axis than make it with the browsers scroll, i have the overflow:hidden of the body

Comment: the problem with scroll event is that increases in speed by time

Comment: oh ok, you want the camera position to change when th page scrolls? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrackballControls` or `OrbitControls` from examples can be used enable zoom (and rotate and pan). See example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=contro#misc_controls_trackball

Include one of the controls that you can find in downloaded package in `three.js-master/examples/js/controls/`:

```html
<script src="three.js-master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

And add to your code

```js
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

And zooming should work out of the box.

If you are only interested in zooming other features can be disabled.

```js
this.enableKeys = false;
this.enablePan = false;
this.enableRotate = false;
```

See also `OrbitControls` sources for more options [OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js)

Comment: i want the mouse wheel change the position.z of camera and use it as a scroll up and down, and after i want only that control,not all the rest that included in the package

Answer (score 0):

now i am here:

```
const scl=0;

$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {


if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {

    while(scl==0) {

        scl+=0.05;
                camera.position.z+=scl;
                //console.log("1."+" "+scl);
    }

} else {

    while(scl==0) {


        scl+=0.05;
                camera.position.z-=scl;
                //console.log("2."+" "+scl);
    }

}
//console.log("3."+" "+scl);;
 scl=0;
});

window.setInterval(function(){
     scl=0;
}, 10);
```

Comment: you answered your own question.... does this mean you solved your issue?

Comment: no,the answer still doesnt work,but the code didnt fit in the comment-answer section,sorry i didnt use jfiddle, i didnt thought about it.

Comment: Hey, I don't remember how I did it, I remember that I had still a problem, the answer is here, if you want to check https://github.com/Phaidonas/WaterEffectMouseOverText?files=1