# three.js move scene one by one by scrolling

Tags: three.js

I'm looking for site that made with three.js

Please refer this sites.

https://www.prokhorov.design/works

https://moxy.studio/

http://vaalentin.github.io/2015/

This sites has similar feature.

When user scroll down once, scene is move to next scene.

Without need to scrolling, just scroll down or up once.

Not only scene is change but also object is change.

Is there any function or method related here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's function or method related there.

Comment: Can you explain about it?

Comment: Do you looking for libraries ?
http://paperjs.org/
https://d3js.org/
https://threejs.org/

Comment: @IsmailFarooq No. Above site using three.js and I'm working with three.js now. I wonder that is there any existed method to implement it in three.js

Comment: @Hide You have to implement your own method to switch scene, capture scroll event, drawing scene, animates elements in the scene by yourself. Three.js  supports all of above that (except for tweening, you might need extra plugins).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change camera position.z with mouse wheel in threejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897577/change-camera-position-z-with-mouse-wheel-in-threejs)